# Zabbix e Telegram, envio de alertas via script

Tags: script, zabbix, telegram

Olá, configurei um script para enviar alertas para grupo/usuario do Telegram, porém não recebo os alertas.

Quando faço teste do script é enviado normalmente. [image: imagem]

Configurei o script no Zabbix, informando os paramentros corretamente.

Quando o alerta é disparado, o Zabbix me retorna que o alerta foi enviado com sucesso, 
porem nao recebo nada e nao tem nada nos logs. [image: imagem].

Obs.:
o script está no diretorio correto e com as devidas permissões.

Alguém ja teve problema semelhante?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Não sei se já resolveu seu problema, mas aqui durante a implantação do script do Telegram no Zabbix, tive que indicar nos parâmetros do script os dados:

{ALERT.SENDTO}
{ALERT.SUBJECT}
{ALERT.MESSAGE}